# Autosave functionality in ck-editor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have implemented ck-editor in my project. User can save data after clicking the save button.but now Client want me to implement auto save functionality for saving data. How can i handle save click event in ck-editor. i want to call save plugin.js after fix time. how can i implement this?

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can use `setInterval` to run a function at time intervals.
This function will run every 2 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Save code goes here
}, 2000); <-- Change this number to the length you want your interval in ms
```

Comment: bro i know the code of setInterval. ck-editor itself handles the save button click event internally. so i am not able to trace out how i can handle the click event. i need help on that.

Comment: @PratikJoshi You asked "i want to call save plugin.js after fix time" which is what I was answering. I don't know how your save code works, so I can't be that specific. All I can suggest is you read the [autosave plugin documentation](http://ckeditor.com/addon/autosave)

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor gives you [`editor#change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event for that purpose. Combined with [`CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-eventsBuffer), which is a kind of de-bouncing utility, it will let you implement safe yet simple auto-save feature:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/WXqc5/).

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    toolbarGroups: [ { name: 'basicstyles' } ],
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            // Autosave but no more frequent than 5 sec.
            var buffer = CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer( 5000, function() {
                console.log( 'Autosave!' );
            } );         

            this.on( 'change', buffer.input );
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

```
        setInterval(function() {        
              CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(9,this);
              return false;
        }, 100000);
```

This code will automatically call the save event of your ck editor. Set this code in your main jsp page where you have implement ck-editor and call this function from   $(document).ready(function(){}
functionality. and its done.

Comment: What's that 9?
You're using a "magical number", it works in your test, but in another browser it can be a different one, or when you update CKEditor it might be assigned to a different function. That's a problem waiting to explode.

Comment: Brother it will remain same for every browser and hang on its not browser dependent. ck editor itself address this number all the time when it call the save function. so it has no connection with browser and yes it is not random as well it will remain same all time.

Comment: yeah, CKEditor developers are so naive that they have created an API where 9 means "save" always, everytime... It will be fun in a few months when the client tries to change anything and that stops working.